# What exactly would happen if this command were run?

Tags: filesystems, rm

A simple curiosity... assuming running as root what would the following command do?

```
# mv / /dev/null
```

Would it be a faster death than `rm -rf` from the root of the tree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would do nothing, for several reasons. The most simple being that you cannot move a directory in a file. You can try that as non-root with a test directory.